# unable to load from yargs in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

[image: unable to load from yargs.argv. i am using npm latest version. its showing undefined in terminal when i use yargs.argv]
unable to load from yargs.argv. i am using npm latest version. its showing undefined in terminal when i use yargs.argv

unable to load from yargs.argv. i am using npm latest version. its showing undefined in terminal when i use yargs.argv

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is no property `argv` on `yargs`.

If you read the documentation, they give examples like:

```
import yargs from 'yargs';

var argv = yargs(process.argv.slice(2));
console.log(argv.argv);
```